# Can not run langchain module , Kernel died while running the script?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, langchain

I was trying to run python script using jupyter notebook as shown below, am not sure on how to troubleshoot moreover the note freezes,

error message

`The kernel appears to have died, it will start automatically`

```
# embeddings using langchain
from langchain.embeddings import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

# using chromadb as a vector store and storing the docs in it
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
db = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embeddings)

# Doing similarity search  using query
query = "What are the different kinds of pets people commonly own?"
matching_docs = db.similarity_search(query)

matching_docs[0]
```

Comment: seems like the computer ran out of memory. Does this happen just once or keep on crashing? try [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com) if that works. Sorry hard to tell what going on with your system.

Comment: Thank you Simple App, yes its working on the Colab,

Comment: glad it worked on Colab :)

Answer (score 1):

while I could not reproduce the exact "Kernel appears to have died" message, I did some experiments with a memory-constrained Python session and Jupyter notebook as well (the [prlimit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/prlimit.1.html) command came handy for this).

It seems that if you stuff your ChromaDB with more documents than your machine's memory can handle, you get a clear `MemoryError` during the `from_documents` method call. However, under a more realistic system strain, it is entirely possible that this was in the end the reason why your kernel died: before exhausting the memory (hence raising the memory exception), other failures creeped in and your kernel just could not keep up with it and panicked out.

As suggested above, you can try running vector-database workload in a cloud environment, which could grant you a more flexible memory (and CPU) plan. For example, [here's a link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/vector_databases/cassandra_astradb/Philosophical_Quotes_cassIO.ipynb) to a Google Colab ready-made notebook that, incidentally, is about experimenting with vector stores as well.

A side note: beyond a certain size, managing an in-memory vector store becomes impractical (even with persistence/reload operations). You could think of extending your exploration to one of the many persistent vector databases out there nowadays. The example I have posted does uses a cloud database-as-a-service with a pretty good vector-db support - which comes with a free tier for testing it out. (Disclaimer: I work at the company that manages it, DataStax).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I thought i9 16 GB RAM would be sufficient but i will check colab,